# Caffe loss doesn't decrease from start to end

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

This is my first time building a net from a paper, as I start training until thousands of iterations, the loss doesn't decrease, instead, it fluctuates all the time, no matter how small I change the base_lr into, like 0.0001, or 0.0000001.I suspect that the data doesn't match to the right label, but how to check it out or what is the solution? This net is about crowd density estimation, both data and label are pictures. I first use matlab to generate density map(label) and name them in order,them create lmdb.

Here is how I name my data:
   [image: Here is how I name my data.]

Here is how I name my label:
 [image: Here is how I name my label]

Here is the solver.

```
net: "/media/lenovo/KINGSTON/UCF_CC_50/UCF_train_test.prototxt"
test_iter: 1
test_interval: 10
base_lr: 0.00001
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.004
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
display: 100
type:"SGD"
max_iter: 20000
snapshot: 2000
snapshot_prefix: "/media/lenovo/KINGSTON/UCF_CC_50/"    
solver_mode: GPU
```

Comment: how do you read the data into caffe? how do you ensure the label image matches the input image?

Comment: I converted them into lmdb files via convert_imageset.exe, I'm not sure if they are matched, so I raised a question here, do you have any idea?

Comment: @did you use the `-shuffle` flag?

Comment: no,  I just resized them

Comment: how did you make the text file listing the images for the data/labels - do the lists match?

Comment: they all start from the first picture to the end, like train_label.txt -dmap\00001.jpg 0
dmap\00002.jpg 1
dmap\00003.jpg 2
dmap\00004.jpg 3......

Comment: could you post your net configuration file? sometimes it's just a matter of weight initialization. I once could not get my net accuracy past 50%, it was only due to the way I was initializing my weights (and biases for that matter)

Comment: @ Levi Albuquerque  they all set like :    weight_filler {      type: 
     "gaussian"
      std: 0.0001   }
    bias_filler {    type: "constant"    }